# How to use Dart 3 Alpha in a Flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've already switch to channel master and running `dart --version` gives me:

Code Block 1

```
Dart SDK version: 3.0.0-178.0.dev (dev) (Fri Jan 27 17:53:41 2023 -0800) on "macos_arm64"
```

However, when I try to use the new syntax for records I get the following:

Code Block 2

```
This requires the 'records' language feature to be enabled.
Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 3.0.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'.
```

I tried to change the sdk version value in pubspec to `^3.0.0,` but I get this:

Code Block 3

```
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.0-178.0.dev.
Because app requires SDK version 3.0.0, version solving failed. exit code 1
```

And if I try to set the version to be specifically `3.0.0-178.0.dev` then I get the error from code block 2, that is:

```
This requires the 'records' language feature to be enabled.

Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 3.0.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'.
```

Comment: The records feature has to be added as an experimental flag. Refer to [this documentation for experiment flags](https://dart.dev/tools/experiment-flags).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can follow these steps.

**Step 1:**  Make sure you are on master branch instead of stable(currently). `flutter --version` will show something like this or later version

```
Flutter 3.7.0-29.0.pre.21 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 75680ae99e (5 hours ago) • 2023-01-28 08:54:06 -0500
Engine • revision 649362168f
Tools • Dart 3.0.0 (build 3.0.0-179.0.dev) • DevTools 2.20.1
```

**Step 2:** config the `analyzsis_options.yaml`

```yaml
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - records
    - patterns
```

You can check &  clone [my experimental_project repository](https://github.com/yeasin50/experimental_project/tree/test-on-3.7.0-29.0.pre.21).

Comment: I may prefer using stable branch for project.

Comment: Then you won't be playing with records or patterns for a while. :)

Comment: Your link https://github.com/yeasin50/experimental_project/tree/test-on-3.7.0-29.0.pre.21 doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: @Stephan make sure to switch on maser branch instead of state to play with it. Also do `flutter upgrade` to get latest changes. PS: I use different environment for playground.

Comment: @Stephan sorry, it was private repo, I've convert it to public now

Comment: Very much appreciated @YeasinSheikh. That worked!

Comment: @YeasinSheikh should the same thing work for `sealed-class`? I've tried these steps, dart is set to Dart 3.0.0 (build 3.0.0-290.0.dev), but I'm still getting the error that the `sealed-class` feature needs to be enabled. My analysis-options file looks the same as yours but with a line for `- sealed-class` as well.

Comment: You can include it on `analyzer` too, I've tested the example and it works, I might not have pushed it on master. I will try to push it on master once I am done with current work.

Comment: Hey, should we change the dart version in pubspec to 3.0.0.dev-something ? Can I keep <3.0.0 ? I followed the instructions but it is not working, still getting the error

Comment: What is the point of adding the experimental flags in the analysis options yaml if you are effectively using dart 3.0.0? where those are enabled by default ?

Comment: The current beta channel has Dart 3.0.0. It's more "stable" than master.

Comment: Do I need to be on the `master` branch to use records & pattern

Comment: @Brendan now it is available on stable branch when you are using  Flutter >=3.10

Answer (score 3):

`Dart 3 is stable` right now
[Flutter 3.10.0 • channel stable]

Read this [medium post](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-3-53f065a10635) for more info

With records, you can build up structured data with a nice and crisp syntax. Consider this function. It reads out the name and age of a JSON blob and returns them both in a record:

```
(String, int) userInfo(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   return (json['name'] as String, json['height'] as int);
}
```

Consider a basic form of a pattern. The following record pattern destructures a record into two new variables name and height. These variables can then be used like any other variable, such as in a call to print:

```
 var (String name, int height) = userInfo({'name': 'Michael', 'height':180}); 
 print('User $name is $height cm tall.');
```

**Records**- There might be situations where you have to return multiple values. You can use records in such situations.

**Patterns**- If something is coming from an unknown source, you can use patterns to check if that particular output matches something. For example, you are getting multiple responses from an API call. The first response will be a success, the second error, and the third success with some other element. So you can have a switch statement with all these patterns, and patterns can match them, and you have your value.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to
environment:
sdk: '>=3.0.3 <4.0.0'