# How to use 'Records & Pattern' language feature in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart3

When I'm trying to use 'records' feature in flutter it shows an error like this,

> This requires the 'records' language feature to be enabled.  Try
> updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.19.0
> or higher, and running 'pub get'.

I changed my pubspec.yaml code and run pub get but it still shows the same error

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.19.0 <3.0.0"
```

for reference - [link](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/records-patterns-824447a9f2b1)

Comment: see https://dart.dev/tools/experiment-flags - you need to enable experiment called `records`

Comment: Dart 3 is stable now so I can use it directly check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76225116/9427138)

Comment: yes, I know - I already switched to 3.10 yesterday