# The class 'StringUtil' can't be used as a mixin because it isn't a mixin class nor a mixin

Tags: flutter, dart

My original goal was to use pattern as experimental flags.

```
(int a, int b) minMax(List<int> list) {
  int min = list[0];
  int max = list[0];
  for (final i in list) {
    if (i < min) {
      min = i;
    }
    if (i > max) {
      max = i;
    }
  }
  return (min, max);
}
```

But I get:

`This requires the 'records' language feature to be enabled`

But in `analysis_options.yaml`, I already added:

```
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - records
    - patterns
    - value-class
```

I did `flutter clean` and `flutter doctor`

`Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.6, on macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)`

So I found this answer [How to use Dart 3 Alpha in a Flutter project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75268891/how-to-use-dart-3-alpha-in-a-flutter-project)

Which says I should switch to master channel. I did.

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.9.0-13.0.pre.11 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 2392be7656 (31 minutes ago) • 2023-03-21 16:22:01 -0400
Engine • revision 87ddd910f1
Tools • Dart 3.0.0 (build 3.0.0-348.0.dev) • DevTools 2.22.2
```

But still getting the error.

So I checked their example repo, in the same answer https://github.com/yeasin50/experimental_project/blob/test-on-3.7.0-29.0.pre.21/pubspec.yaml

And I noticed they changed the Dart version to 3.0.0 in pubspec.yaml which was not mentioned in the answer.

So changed the dart version to

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.0-151.0.dev <4.0.0'
```

And pattern now works but I get a bunch of new errors everywhere in my project.

```
The class 'StringUtil' can't be used as a mixin because it isn't a mixin class nor a mixin.
```

How can I use pattern and keep dart sdk <3.0.0 ? I thought the goal of experimental flags is to do just that. What is the point of adding the experimental flags in the analysis options yaml if you are effectively using dart 3.0.0? where those are enabled by default ? I tested by removing the flags and it is still working on dart 3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

make StringUtil class as mixin not abstract or interface